# Stop background activity flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to stop/block background activities in flutter while there is a loading action like the default behaviour of loaders in any platform.

My purpose is to hold the background steady (no actions should be performed).
Below is my code for reference.

## Auth page

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.NOT_DETERMINED:
        return buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      case AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN:
        return new LoginSignupPage(
          auth: widget.auth,
          loginCallback: loginCallback,
        );
        break;
      case AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN:
        if (_userId.length > 0 && _userId != null) {
          return new HomePage(
            userId: _userId,
            auth: widget.auth,
            logoutCallback: logoutCallback,
          );
        } else
          return buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      default:
        return buildWaitingScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

## buildWaitingScreen()

```dart
  Widget buildWaitingScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now i am able to scroll the background page, click buttons in background page etc which is to be prevented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [ModalBarrier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalBarrier-class.html)

Here is a sample code on how to use this for your use case.

This loads a barrier with loading icon till the timer expires and you cannot interact with the background screen during this interval (try clicking fab icon during this interval).

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleTestState createState() => _SampleTestState();
}

class _SampleTestState extends State<SampleTest> {
  bool _loading;
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    startTimeout(5);
  }

  startTimeout([int seconds]) {
    var duration = Duration(seconds: seconds) ?? Duration(milliseconds: 1500);
    return new Timer(duration, handleTimeout);
  }

  void handleTimeout() {
    // callback function
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _scaffold(),
        Visibility(
          visible: _loading,
          child: _showLoading(context),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _scaffold() => Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            print("FAB pressed");
            setState(() {
              _counter +=1;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: _body(),
      );

  Widget _body() => Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 500,
          width: 300,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(_counter == 0 ? "FAB not clicked" : "Fab clicked $_counter times !"),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _showLoading(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ModalBarrier(
          dismissible: false,
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```